# do oncalculate fields in one table using values from another table

Tags: delphi

I am doing calculations in my KLOG table.
However, my PRICES table has the data I need for the calculations in the KLOG table.

Example :
KLOG table has PRICE_ID field (integer). So does the PRICES table.

So I am trying to do something like this (oncalculatefields of the KLOG table ) :

```
if KLOG.FieldByName('PRICE_ID') = 1 then begin
KLOG.FieldByName('calculated_field_value_1').Value := KLOG.FieldByName('calculated_field_value_2').Value +5;
```

This (+5) however is a field value (BONUS)  in my PRICES table where PRICE_ID =1.

So how can I reference this BONUS field in my oncalculate event of the KLOG table?
Can you use SELECT ? Something like :

```
KLOG.FieldByName('calculated_field_value_1').Value := KLOG.FieldByName('calculated_field_value_2').Value + (select BONUS from PRICES where PRICES.PRICE_ID = KLOG.PRICE_ID);
```

Not sure I am writing this properly.

Comment: Can you return the BONUS field as part of the original query that returns the KLOG table data?

Comment: Just add a second query and look up BONUS from your PRICES table. Use parameters and check the existing value of the PRICE_ID parameter before closing and re-opening it.

Comment: If it is possible do not doing any calculations on the client-side. Almost any DBMSs was developed for calculations on the server side and to not disturb clients PCs for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not telling us what data access component you are using.

The recommended way to do this is using a Query component (`TSQLQuery`, `TADOQuery`, `TIBQuery`,...) , then have the SQL for that query retrieve all necessary information. All the fields that you want access to in you `OnCalcFields()` should be in that query.

It would be something like

```
select * from KLOG, PRICES
where KLOG.PRICE_ID=PRICES.PRICE_ID
```

Replace the * with the field names you actually want.
If you want to, you can even do simple calculation in the query already, e.g. something like

```
select [..], PRICES.PRICE*KLOG_QUANTITY as TotalPrice from KLOG, PRICES
where KLOG.PRICE_ID=PRICES.PRICE_ID
```

Using query components instead of table components is good practice anyway; (together with `TClientDataSet`...) it will generally allow you to retrieve smaller amounts of data than an entire table.

Comment: Ahh,I get it.... you must first run a query to get the result and then pass the result to on-calculate fields of the table. I used Jans first suggestion.Thank you all.